# ElasticSearch AWS plugin is a must to deploy on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

We are planning to deploy our ElasticSearch on Amazon Web Services. I noticed that there is a plugin from ElasticSearch that allows ElasticSearch to use AWS API for the unicast discovery mechanism. [ElasticSearch Cloud AWS](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws).

My questions are:

- Should I use that plugin? or it is something nice to have but not required ?
- What is the effect of not using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the plugin.

If you don't then you'll have to put the addresses of the nodes in your configuration file by hand (since multicast is not available)

The ec2 plugin can also set the availability zone of instances as node attributes - this can be used to tell elasticsearch not to put primary and replica shards in the same availability zone. Again you could do this by hand

Comment: Just to summerise: Without using the plugin, you need to be certain that the IPs for the unicast seed hosts will never change. Also, it helps to backup to S3.